# How to minimize all opened items (appointment) using macro in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I am new in VBA macro programming, can anyone give an example vba macro script to minimize all opened items (appointments) in outlook.

I get example from
https://www.slipstick.com/developer/outlook-vba-work-with-open-item-or-select-item/
and
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.activewindow
but both example only minimize the currect active item window (not all minimize)

Any body can help me please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Outlook object model provides the [WindowState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.windowstate) property for that out of the box. It returns or sets the property with a constant in the `OlWindowState` enumeration specifying the window state of an explorer or inspector window.

```
Application.ActiveWindow.WindowState = olMinimized
```

If you need to minimize all Outlook windows (inspectors) you need to iterate over all inspectors in the `Inspectors` collection and set the property like shown above.

```
 Dim myInspectors As Outlook.Inspectors  
 Dim x as Integer  
 Dim iCount As Integer  
 
 Set myInspectors = Application.Inspectors  
 iCount = Application.Inspectors.Count  
 If iCount > 0 Then 
   For x = 1 To iCount 
     myInspectors.Item(x).WindowState = olMinimized
   Next x  
 Else  
   MsgBox "No inspector windows are open."  
 End If
```

To minimize Outlook windows you can also use Windows API functions. The [ShowWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow) function does the trick. You just need to pass the `SW_MINIMIZE` value which minimizes the specified window and activates the next top-level window in the Z order.

Comment: Thank you Eugene for your guide. very helpfull.